# Keep reading user keyboard input if available, while echoing back the latest available

Tags: multithreading, haskell, functional-programming, concurrency

On StackOverflow I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63874453/keep-reading-user-keyboard-input-if-available-while-echoing-back-the-latest-ava/) a few minutes ago, but then by trying a bit more, I found the answer myself, and I'm posting the resulting working code here for review.

What the code does, is waiting for, and repeatedly prompting the user to enter a character; when the user enters one, the program echoes it back and goes back to the previous mode, waiting for further input. The program assumes an initial implicit input of `'A'`.

```hs
{-# language LambdaCase #-}

import Control.Concurrent
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  future_input <- newEmptyMVar
  work future_input 'l'

work :: MVar Char -> Char -> IO ()
work future_input latest_input = do
  forkIO $ putMVar future_input =<< getChar
  wait future_input latest_input
    where
      wait :: MVar Char -> Char -> IO ()
      wait future_input latest_input =
        tryTakeMVar future_input >>=
          \case Just input -> putStrLn ("new input " ++ return input)
                              >> work future_input input
                Nothing    -> putStrLn ("old input " ++ return latest_input)
                              >> threadDelay 100000
                              >> wait future_input latest_input
```

Some thoughts on about the code:

- I've tried to use applicative/monadic style wherever I could, without compromising readability too much;
- as regards the concurrentcy-handling part, basically the `wait` function, I preferred using the `do` sugar because I could hardly get something working this way.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of suggestion/help on Haskell's IRC channels, I came up with this, which doesn't `forkIO` at every recursion.

```hs
{-# language LambdaCase #-}

import Control.Concurrent
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  future_input <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ pollInput future_input
  processInput future_input 'l'

pollInput :: MVar Char -> IO ()
pollInput future_input = (putMVar future_input =<< getChar) >> pollInput future_input

processInput :: MVar Char -> Char -> IO ()
processInput future_input latest_input = tryTakeMVar future_input >>=
    \case Just input -> putStrLn ("direction change " ++ return input)
                        >> processInput future_input input
          Nothing    -> putStrLn ("keep direction " ++ return latest_input)
                        >> threadDelay 100000
                        >> processInput future_input latest_input
```